# Postgres/Redshift DATEDIFF convert to FLOAT

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I am using Python SQLAlchemy to connect to a Redshift instance. I am trying to calculate a DATEDIFF in minutes between 2 datetimes, which works. But when I try to CAST the result to FLOAT and use it in a CASE WHEN against ' < 1' , I get only 'THEN' results?

```
SELECT distinct u2.id,
  CASE 
    WHEN 
      CAST(DATEDIFF(minute, u1.usa_start_datetime::timestamp,u1.usa_end_datetime::timestamp) * 1.00 as FLOAT) < 1.00 
      THEN 1.00 END as fsess_hr,
```

Comment: What result are you expecting?  There's no `ELSE` clause, so you'll get `1.0` or `NULL` only.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing an `ELSE` clause in your `CASE` statement. If you want to get `1.0` if the difference is less than 1 and the difference as a floating point number otherwise, modify your query as follows:

```
SELECT distinct 
       u2.id,
       CASE 
         WHEN CAST(DATEDIFF(minute, u1.usa_start_datetime::timestamp,u1.usa_end_datetime::timestamp) * 1.00 as FLOAT) < 1.00 THEN 1.00 
         ELSE CAST(DATEDIFF(minute, u1.usa_start_datetime::timestamp,u1.usa_end_datetime::timestamp) * 1.00 as FLOAT) 
       END as fsess_hr
  FROM some_table
```

Also, I don't think you need the `* 1.00`

Answer (score 1):

The return type of [`DATEDIFF()`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_DATEDIFF_function.html) is `BIGINT` and you have chosen to use minutes as the unit. So deal with the integers within the `case expression` then cast the value to float

```
SELECT /* DISTINCT */ -- is this really needed? 
      u2.id
    , CAST(
            CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(MINUTE, u1.usa_start_datetime ::timestamp, u1.usa_end_datetime ::timestamp)  < 1 THEN 1
                 ELSE DATEDIFF(MINUTE, u1.usa_start_datetime ::timestamp, u1.usa_end_datetime ::timestamp)
            END 
      AS Float) AS fsess_hr
FROM ...
```

**BUT** you are still returning a number of minutes, so I don't follow why it is called fsess_hr, do you divide it by 60.0 at some point?

Answer (score 0):

I find that ::float works with datediff just fine. Looks cleaner than `cast() as float`

```
SELECT distinct u2.id,
CASE 
    WHEN DATEDIFF(minute,u1.usa_start_datetime::timestamp,u1.usa_end_datetime::timestamp)::float < 1.00 
THEN 1.00 END as fsess_hr,
```